# How do you only display a piece of a template on certain pages in Umbraco CMS?

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I have a site built with Umbraco that has a sidebar with several widgets setup.  I need to set it so that one of the widgets (done as XSLT) will only display on a certain page.  I've looked at using xsl:if test and matches and can't figure it out.

Comment: So what is the question? I can't see one.

Comment: The question was the title can you not read?

Comment: cstrouse: I can read and reading the title it doesn't make sense to me -- what do you mean by "piece of a template"? I hoped that this would be clarified in the contents of the question -- alas this was unreasonable expectation. There is no source XML document specified and there is no wanted result from the transformation specified. There is no XSLT code whatsoever. You only state the fact that you "can't figure it out" without telling us what this "it" is.

Comment: I wanted to know if I could render partial templates using XSLT.  I'm not very familiar with ASP but in Rails use render_partial to render these template pieces.

Comment: OK, so by "templates" you mean something different than XSLT templates -- *now* I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but get into the habit of including what you have tried already in your question (code etc).

**The Quick + Dirty Method**

Find out the ID of you page (found on the properties tab of your node in the Content section) and use the following code:

```
<xsl:if test="$currentPage/@id = 1234">
    <!-- your widget here -->
</xsl:if>
```

**The Cleaner Method**

Always try to build your code to be scalable, for instance you may find that you want to include the widget on another page in the future, or deploying your content from staging to production might involve the node IDs changing without you realizing (not often, but can happen).

Add a property to the page in question (let's call it `showMyFancyWidget`) as true/false data type, flick it on in the Content section then use the following code:

```
<xsl:if test="$currentPage/showMyFancyWidget = 1">
    <!-- your widget here -->
</xsl:if>
```

*This code will work for Umbraco v4.5.1 onwards. Not too sure about v5, but that's being discontinued in favor of v4.7 anyway*